# hardware configuration for data science

Tags: python, data-science-model, hardware

I would like to know what type of computer configuration to use to perform datascience on medium to low quantity of data (< 100 000 matrix line x 50 parameters).

I have read some blog on people building their own system, but I am performing regressions essentially. Sklearn is quite well designed to me and 1 GPU with cuda would be enough for the rest.

I am surprise to read no feedback about "standard" computer designed for gaming. They are maybe missing a bit of RAM, but after that they look not so bad.

For example, a computer like an ASUS ROG HURACAN present interesting configuration for an accessible price.

Am I missing a key point? any feedback to share? benchmark to share?

thx for help!

Comment: for that size of data and the types of tasks you don't need a GPU and I would assume any modern, affordable off-the-shelve laptop will work just fine for your purposes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. this is what I believed so, but in the end, at which moment are people needing GPU ?